# What's the name of this style of chart?

Tags: chart-design, chart

Does anyone know what these charts are called?

[image]

**edit:** I think it's 'radial timeline'

Comment: "Circle Infographic"? If it's not time based. See: https://www.pinterest.com/explore/circle-infographic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I could come up with would be a **Timeline** chart formatted to a circle.

It's clearly a Timeline chart, but I do not know if there's a *specific* name beyond that merely because it's formatted to a circle.

Comment: I googled 'circular timeline' and got some pertinent results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a radial bar chart / graph. For sure :)